# Does a permanent magnet attract a positively charged rod?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, charge

I thought that because the charge on the rod is static, there wouldn't be an interaction with the magnetic field, however the answer to the question states that both poles of the magnet would attract the rod. Thanks!

Edit: The question does not state the material the rod is made of. Here's the exact question.

> A positively, electrically charged rod is brought near a permanent magnet. What will be observed?

Comment: What  is the rod made of ?

Comment: Charged objects can attract neutral objects.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a charged object can attract a neutral conductor by [inducing dipole polarization](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-1/Polarization); the fact that your neutral conductor is magnetic is a red herring.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you know about the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). Moving charges will be deflected under the influence of an external magnetic field. So if you move a rod with free electrons into a magnetic field the electrons move according the right hand rule:

[image]

After the rod left the field or after the rod comes to rest the charges will be uniform distributed again.